# Issues Authenticating google sign in

Tags: flutter, dart

Please, I need a help in authenticating google signing in my application. Below is my authentication code maybe there is something i am not getting right. I keep getting this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':google_sign_in:compileDebugAidl'.

> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-29' in: C:\Users\Dennis\AppData\Local

```
Future<User>gSignin() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);

  final UserCredential authResult =
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

  final User user = authResult.user;

  final User currentUser = _auth.currentUser;

  assert(currentUser.uid == user.uid);

  print('User: ${user.displayName}');

  return user;
}

Pubspec.yaml

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+2
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.10.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.5
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
```

Please i need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "^" from   `google_sign_in: ^4.5.5`

if it does not work for you, try this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58115#issuecomment-642438499)